# RecyclerView doesn't recognize the view holder

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin by building an app and now, I'm trying to create an adapter for my RecyclerView.  However, the name that I chose for my ViewGroup is marked as `Unresolved Reference`.  I'm fairly new to Kotlin so I knew I was going to make a dumb mistake but in this case, I couldn't figure out what I did wrong.

```
class RecyclerAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.PosterHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerAdapter.PosterHolder, position: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}

class PosterHolder (v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I literally had to re-implement the functions.  I think this is an Android Studio issue, as opposed to Kotlin.  Here is my most up to date code:

```
class RecyclerAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<PosterHolder>(){

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PosterHolder, position: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PosterHolder{
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}

class PosterHolder (v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to fix:

```js
class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.PosterHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PosterHolder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PosterHolder, position: Int) {

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    inner class PosterHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

> And to convert java file to kotlin file with Android Studio, choosing
>   Code->Convert java file to kotlin file.